# Javascript on JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I'm trying to build a tablesorter on JSFiddle.

The link to the table is below.

I'm wanting to make the Genre and Age Rating drop down menus like the Release Date column. I'm struggling to code it correctly, as when I copy the other code I already have and attach it to the Genre columns then the Javascript stops working completely.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Video Game</th>
            <th>Release Date</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>Age Rating</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Game 1</td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>11th June</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Sport</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>16</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Game 2 </td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>11th July</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Sci-Fi</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>18</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {

    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_functions: {
                1: {
                    "January": function (e, n) {
                        return /January/.test(n);
                    },
                        "February": function (e, n) {
                        return /February/.test(n);
                    },
                        "March": function (e, n) {
                        return /March/.test(n);
                    },
                        "April": function (e, n) {
                        return /April/.test(n);
                    },
                        "May": function (e, n) {
                        return /May/.test(n);
                    },
                        "June": function (e, n) {
                        return /June/.test(n);
                    },
                        "July": function (e, n) {
                        return /July/.test(n);
                    },
                        "August": function (e, n) {
                        return /August/.test(n);
                    },
                        "September": function (e, n) {
                        return /September/.test(n);
                    },
                        "October": function (e, n) {
                        return /October/.test(n);
                    },
                        "November": function (e, n) {
                        return /November/.test(n);
                    },
                        "December": function (e, n) {
                        return /December/.test(n);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Visit the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/6091/)

Comment: Thomas, [you were warned about this style of asking a question earlier today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888337/javascript-writing-on-jsfiddle). Why are you still doing it? Did you read the documentation that T.J. provided?

Comment: This is his link actually http://jsfiddle.net/abknm/6091/

Comment: Thomas, Please edit your question with the actual link to the fiddle. I found it in the comments: http://jsfiddle.net/abknm/6091/

Comment: Flagged the question as unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add additonal filter functions:

```
filter_functions: {
    1: {
        "January": function (e, n) {
            return /January/.test(n);
        },
        "February": function (e, n) {
            return /February/.test(n);
        },
        // other months
    },
    2: {
        "Sport": function (e, n) {
            return /Sport/.test(n);
       },
        "Sci-Fi": function (e, n) {
            return /Sci-Fi/.test(n);
       }
    },
    3: {
        "16": function (e, n) {
            return /16/.test(n);
       },
        "18": function (e, n) {
            return /18/.test(n);
       }
    }
}
```

It will create dropdown menus under Genre with the options Sport and Sci-Fi and another one under Age Rating with the options 16 and 18. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Great awnser to a terrible question

Comment: @CKY thanks. I hope that is what the author is asking for.

Comment: Sorry CKY, not all of us have the skills in Javascript, nor the time, that's why forums like these were created. If you have a problem with it then remove yourself from the topic.

Comment: @TTT I don't think CKY wanted to be rude, but your initial question wasn't really formulated well. Now it looks much better with the correct link and the code provided nicely formatted.

Comment: @TTT NOT THE TIME? Come on most of the people work in programming and then you dont have time come on..... Its not a free programming forum so people can get free websites. Yes you have shown some afford and the code you have is great but when you say stuff like that. Dayum dude.....